# Restangular POST request not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

I am trying to do a POST request to an REST api. when i try it using restangular with the following code

```
 var cust={'name':'test'};
return Restangular.all('enquiry').post(cust).then(function(response) {
            console.log("Object saved OK");
        }, function(response) {
          console.log("There was an error saving");
          console.log(response);
        });
```

Am geting a error in console as

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/api/enquiry. The request was redirected to 'http://localhost/?search=', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

This means the Server is not considering the request as POST so url redirection not going to the proper API page

But when i try POST request with Google chrome REST console its going to the proper API page and getting the expected result

```
POST http://localhost/api/enquiry 502 (Bad Gateway)request.js:1 b.RESTRequest.Class.sendmootools-core-1.4.0.js:1 b.extend.$ownerapp.js:1 document.getElement.addEvents.submitmootools-core-1.4.0.js:1 (anonymous function)mootools-core-1.4.0.js:1 (anonymous function)mootools-core-1.4.0.js:1 Array.implement.eachmootools-core-1.4.0.js:1 invoke.fireEventapp.js:1 document.getElement.addEvents.postmootools-core-1.4.0.js:1 (anonymous function)mootools-core-1.4.0.js:1 (anonymous function)mootools-core-1.4.0.js:1 Array.implement.eachmootools-core-1.4.0.js:1 invoke.fireEventapp.js:1 document.getElement.addEvents.click:relay(input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"])mootools-core-1.4.0.js:1 lmootools-core-1.4.0.js:1 dmootools-core-1.4.0.js:1 o
```

Event though the result in REST console is a 502 error, it was expected.
I have noticed that With REST Console the out put was POST http://localhost/api/enquiry 502 (Bad Gateway) and with restangular its XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/api/enquiry
Why the request send through the Restangular not considering as a POST request in server but in REST Console its working?

Server side accepted headers are

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Comment: you are getting CORS error check your server configuration...

Comment: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); is present in the server so will this create a problem.?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the restangular POST request code to

```
return Restangular.all('enquiry').post(cust,'',{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}).then(function(response) {
        console.log("Object saved OK");
    }, function(response) {
      console.log("There was an error saving");
      console.log(response);
    });
```

Content-type header has solved the issue.